# List of Camel routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel in java ee project with wildfly.

Do routes with DSL, like this:

```
from("direct:route1").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // bla-bal-bale
    }
}).to("direct:route2");
```

Sometimes I get errors, so I need to check routes
How to get all of Camel routes? Maybe there is any maven command?

Answer (score 2):

To view the routes from your live Camel application, you would have to use JMX; since you need to access them from the terminal you can use [jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/).

For a list of functionality/data that Camel exposes through JMX, as well as for other configuration instructions, I suggest you give [the official documentation a look](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you must use a terminal then jmxterm as miloš-milivojević mentions will work.

If you can use a browser then I'd recommend running http://hawt.io/ on the same server. This provides a prettier JConsole via a browser with added functionality for viewing Camel routes (e.g. you can stop/start/debug routes)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the CamelContext object.
That supports a method with the signature:

```
Collection<Endpoint> getEndpoints();
```

You can iterate through that collection to get the various endpoints, and check for information you need. For example:

```
Collection<Endpoint> endPoints = context.getEndpoints();   
for (Endpoint nxtEndPoint : endPoints)
{
    System.out.println("ENDPOINT:"+ nxtEndPoint.getEndpointUri());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do it in terminal?

Comment: What terminal? Is this something specific to WildFly ?

Comment: Look, I use linux, Is possible check routes without running wildfly from home directory?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to deploy to to something like Karaf. There in the Karaf terminal you can run commands to check, start and stop routes.

Answer (score 0):

Use "route-list" command to see routes in Apache Karaf